# Azure Function EventHub Trigger Blob output with Managed Identity auth

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to create an Azure Function in JAVA that has an EventHub Trigger. Inside the payload of each event that the function receives, comes the path of a blob and moves that blob to another container in another Storage Account.

For this, I'm not using any kind of binding, just the trigger.

So far I have been able to make it work without any problem and I authenticate against the EventHub using **Managed Identity** and **not via Connection String**. However, to move the blob I do use connection String as I use the `com.microsoft.azure.storage` package.

Azure Storage client code snipet:

```java
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccountDest;
        CloudBlobClient blobClientDest = null;
        CloudBlobContainer containerDest = null;

        String storageConnectionStringDest = System.getenv("AzureStorageDemoConnectionStringDest");

        storageAccountDest = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionStringDest);
        blobClientDest = storageAccountDest.createClientCloudBlob();
        containerDest = blobClientDest.getContainerReference("<DEST-CONTAINER>");
```

Is there any way I can easily connect against Storage Account using Managed Identity?

Here the Function code:

```java
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;  
import org.json.JSONArray;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

/**
 * Azure Functions with Event Hub trigger.
 */
public class EventHubTriggerBlobStorageSink {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when an event is received from Event Hub.
     */
    @FunctionName("EventHubTriggerBlobStorageSink")
    public void run(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "message", eventHubName = "<EH-NAME>", 
        connection = "<EH-CONNECTION-STRING-MI>", consumerGroup = "$Default", cardinality = Cardinality.MANY) List<String> message,
        final ExecutionContext context)
        throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException
        {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccountDest;
        CloudBlobClient blobClientDest = null;
        CloudBlobContainer containerDest = null;

        String storageConnectionStringDest = System.getenv("AzureStorageDemoConnectionStringDest");

        storageAccountDest = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionStringDest);
        blobClientDest = storageAccountDest.createCloudBlobClient();
        containerDest = blobClientDest.getContainerReference("<CONTAINER-NAME>");


        message.forEach(singleMessage -> {

            /* 1. COPY BLOB INTO DEST */

          /* 2. DELETE BLOB INTO SOURCE */

        });
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a code snippet from this thread: [Provide some Java code sample for using Managed Identity](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59673)

The interesting part:

```java
import com.azure.identity.*;
...
String endpoint = "https://<storageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net";
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
  .endpoint(endpoint)
  .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
  .buildClient();
```

Full sample app can be found [here](https://github.com/gary918/AzureStorage/blob/master/AzureStorageManagedIdentity/src/main/java/com/blobs/quickstart/App.java)

Comment: Hi @Thomas Sorry for the delay in my reply. Thank you very much for the input :). The solution at the end differs a bit from your code snippet. Instead of `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder` I use `ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder`.

Comment: no worries, the `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder ` will allow you to debug from your favorite IDE as well.